# How to Get Mail Body which has .eml attachment?

Tags: python, email, imap, email-client, imaplib

I am developing Email client Application in Python.

How to Get Mail Body which has .eml attachment using Imap ?

Answer (score 0):

The code below does the job. You need python2.7 to run the below code, because this was coded back in the days. However, your question was from back in the days too so I guess that's fine. The code is pretty straight-forwards hence please take a look.

```
from email import message_from_file
import os

def file_exists (f):
    return os.path.exists(os.path.join(path, f).replace("\\","/"))

def save_file (fn, cont):
    file = open(os.path.join(path, fn).replace("\\","/"), "wb")
    file.write(cont)
    file.close()

def construct_name (id, fn):
    id = id.split(".")
    id = id[0]+id[1]
    return id+"."+fn

def disqo (s):
    s = s.strip()
    if s.startswith("'") and s.endswith("'"): return s[1:-1]
    if s.startswith('"') and s.endswith('"'): return s[1:-1]
    return s

def disgra (s):
    s = s.strip()
    if s.startswith("<") and s.endswith(">"): return s[1:-1]
    return s

def pullout (m, key):
    Html = ""
    Text = ""
    Files = {}
    Parts = 0
    if not m.is_multipart():
        if m.get_filename():
            fn = m.get_filename()
            cfn = construct_name(key, fn)
            Files[fn] = (cfn, None)
            if file_exists(cfn): return Text, Html, Files, 1
            save_file(cfn, m.get_payload(decode=True))
            return Text, Html, Files, 1
        cp = m.get_content_type()
        if cp=="text/plain": Text += m.get_payload(decode=True)
        elif cp=="text/html": Html += m.get_payload(decode=True)
        else:
            cp = m.get("content-type")
            try: id = disgra(m.get("content-id"))
            except: id = None
            o = cp.find("name=")
            if o==-1: return Text, Html, Files, 1
            ox = cp.find(";", o)
            if ox==-1: ox = None
            o += 5; fn = cp[o:ox]
            fn = disqo(fn)
            cfn = construct_name(key, fn)
            Files[fn] = (cfn, id)
            if file_exists(cfn): return Text, Html, Files, 1
            save_file(cfn, m.get_payload(decode=True))
        return Text, Html, Files, 1
    y = 0
    while 1:
        try:
            pl = m.get_payload(y)
        except: break
        t, h, f, p = pullout(pl, key)
        Text += t; Html += h; Files.update(f); Parts += p
        y += 1
    return Text, Html, Files, Parts

def extract (msgfile, key): 
    m = message_from_file(msgfile)
    From, To, Subject, Date = caption(m)
    Text, Html, Files, Parts = pullout(m, key)
    Text = Text.strip(); Html = Html.strip()
    msg = {"subject": Subject, "from": From, "to": To, "date": Date,
        "text": Text, "html": Html, "parts": Parts}
    if Files: msg["files"] = Files
    return msg

def caption (origin):
    Date = ""
    if origin.has_key("date"): Date = origin["date"].strip()
    From = ""
    if origin.has_key("from"): From = origin["from"].strip()
    To = ""
    if origin.has_key("to"): To = origin["to"].strip()
    Subject = ""
    if origin.has_key("subject"): Subject = origin["subject"].strip()
    return From, To, Subject, Date

if __name__ == "__main__":
    global path

    startdirname = "Email"
    num = 1
    for i in range(10000000):
        if os.path.exists(startdirname + str(num)) == False:
            os.makedirs("Email" + str(num))
            break
        else:
            num += 1


    for i in os.listdir("."):
        if i.endswith(".eml") == True:
            nam = i[:-4]
            path = "./" + startdirname + str(num) + "/" + nam

            os.makedirs("./" + startdirname + str(num) + "/" + nam)

            f = open(i, "rb")
            emailDict = extract(f, f.name)
            f.close()

            textFile = ""

            froms = emailDict["from"]
            tos = emailDict["to"]
            subject = emailDict["subject"]
            parts = emailDict["parts"]
            date = emailDict["date"]
            txt = emailDict["text"]
            html = emailDict["html"]

            files = []
            for i in emailDict["files"]:
                files.append(i)

            textFile += "From: " + froms + "\n"
            textFile += "To: " + tos + "\n"
            textFile += "Subject: " + subject + "\n"
            textFile += "Date: " + date + "\n\n"
            textFile += "Files: " + ", ".join(files) + "\n"
            textFile += "Parts: " + str(parts) + "\n\n"
            textFile += "Text:\n\n" + txt + "\n\n" 
            textFile += "HTML:\n\n" + html


            wf = open("./" + startdirname + str(num) + "/" + nam + "/" + "txt_" + nam + ".txt", "w")
            wf.write(textFile)
            wf.close()
```